# Extracting a very large file (400GB+) from a .rar archive without the computer freezing

Tags: extract, rar

I've have a very large file (433GB) in a splitted .rar file.

While extracting it the WinRAR program always freezes, and it's a very long process prone to errors or last-minute failures.

Do you have any ideas about how to reliably extract this file (maybe partially)?

Linux / programming solutions are also welcome.

Comment: If you have a multi-part rar file, there is no way to unrar just part of that file. I would suggest trying to get the source of the file to create a smaller archive or split the actual data set into multiple sets/rar files. If this is not possible, then extraction of the whole thing is necessary.

Comment: You may find an alternative extractor, like `7-Zip` (there are both installable and portable versions), will be less error-prone. Don't extract into an NTFS compressed directory: this gives errors on large files.

Answer (score -1):

Linux:

```
cat one.rar two.rar three.rar > one-big.rar
```

then

```
unrar one-big.rar
```

Comment: Downvote why? This method will work.

Comment: I suspect the downvote is because the post doesn't explain *how* this answers the question. See [answer].